# calling ajax route in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

```
view
==========
$('#searchstudent').on('click',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formdata = $('#searchform').serialize();
    console.log(formdata);
         $.ajax({
            url:'/test',
            type:'post', 
            dataType:'json', 
            data : formdata ,
            success : function(data){
                console.log('hey'+data);
            }
         });
      });
```

route

```
Route::post('/test', ['as'=>'test','uses'=>'HomeController@test']);
```

controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

public function test(Request $request){
    return response()->json(['name' => 'praveen', 'country' => 'SL']);
 }
```

Issues I Face

1)Currently i am in this url

```
http://localhost/blog/allocatestudent/1
```

from this url only my view is rendered and from here i am calling above  mentioned ajax function

Error message i got from console

```
POST http://localhost/test 404 (Not Found)
```

What i tried to change the url in ajax function like below

```
url:'test' instead of url:'/test'
```

and in my route

```
Route::post('test', ['as'=>'test','uses'=>'HomeController@test']);
```

so i am getting another error message as

```
POST http://localhost/blog/allocatestudent/test 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Anybody can tell me where i am doing wrong?...

Comment: What happens when you've change the url from '/test' to 'http://localhost/blog/allocatestudent/test'? (try to add http://) before here

Comment: if i use like 
    Route::post('/allocatestudent/test',    ['as'=>'test','uses'=>'HomeController@test']);  then it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify the AJAX URL with an leading slash (like `/test`), it will handle the request as absolute path (like `yourdomain.com/test`), in your case `localhost/test`.

Change the URL to the whole absolute path, but without your domain:
`/blog/allocatestudent/test`

AJAX will interpret it as `localhost/blog/allocatestudent/test`

The best (durable and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) solution would be to create a function that returns the url with the fixed path before.

```
var BASE_URL = '/blog';

function getUrl(url) {
    return BASE_URL.concat(url);
}

console.log(getUrl("/allocatestudent/test")); //returns "/blogallocatestudent/test
```

Comment: Thank u so much manniL 
    localhost/blog this is my project url.and now am in 
    localhost/blog/allocatestudent/1 url. so from here can u suggest
    me in 
    my ajax url what should i give?.. and in my route what should i give? 
    inorder to execute my function in controller named test...

Comment: Your route should be start with `allocatestudent/{id}` or similar. The base URL should not be included in your route file, but in your ajax request. There the url should be `/blog/allocatestudent/1`